# How to clear stored local storage value if the user open second html page independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Working on local storage using jQuery. I have two pages. In the first page I have 3 radio buttons and in the second page I have some text fields where if the user selects the second radio button from the first page in the second page the validation was not working.

I got this help from SO user "Sparky" but the problem is if the user open the second page independently the localstorage was not clearing the data even if I cleared cache.

I have tried using `localStorage.removeItem("CheckedRadioValue");` This was working fine but the problem is if the user came from first page by mistaken user refresh the page the localstorage value getting clear

**My Goal**

If the user open the second page it has to work as expected he didn't come from first page all field should get validated.

Jquery code

**First page**

```
function assignValue() {
    var checkedRadioValue = -1;
    if (document.getElementById("ug").checked) {
        checkedRadioValue = 1;
    } else if (document.getElementById("pg").checked) {
        checkedRadioValue = 2;
    } else if (document.getElementById("cu").checked) {
        checkedRadioValue = 3;
    }
    //localStorage.setItem("CheckedRadioValue", checkedRadioValue);
    if (window.localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem("CheckedRadioValue", checkedRadioValue);
    }
}
assignValue();
```

**Second page**

```
var checkedRadioValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("CheckedRadioValue"));
if (checkedRadioValue != -1) {
    if (checkedRadioValue === 1) {
        $('.local_Field ').each(function() {
            $(this).rules("remove", "required");
        });
    } else if (checkedRadioValue === 3) {
        $('.local_Field').each(function() {
            $(this).rules("remove", "required");
        });
        $("#edu_info").hide();
        $(".local_Field").removeClass('required_Field');
        //$('.local_Field ').addClass('chumma');
    } else {
        $('.local_Field ').each(function() {
            $(this).rules("add", "required");
        });
        //$(".local_Field").addClass('required_Field');
    };
    //localStorage.removeItem("CheckedRadioValue");
}
```

Comment: ok thanks  are you praising or shouting me @T.J.Crowder :)

Comment: Please provide the fiddle link if any to better understand the problem

Comment: @AkshayaRaghuvanshi sorry i have two html file i don't no how to do it in jsfiddle

Comment: Do you have to use localStorage? Can't you just post to the second page?

Comment: @Mahadevan: Neither, shouting would be rude. Please just refrain from such comments in questions in the future, they have no place.

Comment: yes sure i will do it :)

Comment: The beginning of your question is about five times longer than is useful. We don't need to know the history of your developing this page. We just need to know 1. What you're expecting, 2. What sequence of operations, specifically, you're doing. 3. What's happening that you don't expect.

Comment: Sure I will take care this points next time i  when i ask the question i will

Comment: Exactly, @Mahadevan please be precise to your question. We don't need anything else. Even i couldn't understand after reading it through.

Comment: You could just refine this question.

Comment: @RobinDorbell  thanks for the reply No I have to use localStorage

Comment: Do i need to change title again

Comment: Title is ok, just : 1. Your goal, 2. What you expect from the code. 3. What's the output and why it not met your expect. Currently, I'm not sure whether you want to remove the cache or you want to keep the record.

Comment: @Mahadevan Ok, then how about clearing the localStorage only after the user continues from page 2?

Comment: I have edited the question kindly check

Comment: So you want, when people come from page 1, the record keeps even if user mistakenly refresh page 2, on the other hand, if user comes from other place, there should not be any record?

Comment: yes @fuyushimoya this is what i want

Comment: Maybe [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) is what you want.

Comment: @fuyushimoya is that possible can you please provide me a sample so i can try to implement the same

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qrvef2y9/7/ shows and idea how you may do it. Not a real working example because jsfiddle runs in an iframe, so its refererr will be `https://jsfiddle.net/.....`.

Comment: Have you tried using `sessionStorage`?